# How to remove title bar in support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to port my app to android support library v7 revision 23.1.

For this purpose I have extended my theme from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar as instructed in multitude of guides.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent=" Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar ">
```

The problem is that the activity shows old android title bar with the name of my application and I cannot remove this title bar. Regarding this the support library is a big step backwards in comparison to holoeverywhere. Not to mention load of other bugs.

I have tried to remove title bar using following adition to my theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent=" Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar ">
    ...
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

But the title bar persists.
The device runs with android 2.3.5.
How to remove title bar?

Comment: Are you using this style in your Activity?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes.

Comment: @karaokyo See my question.

Comment: This is no where close to an MCVE. If you really did create an MCVE project, post the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

You must set

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

also using toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/activity_main_page_toolbar"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
      android:textColorPrimary="@android:color/white"
      app:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAppCompat">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                        android:background="@drawable/menu_item_drawable"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon" />

     <include layout="@layout/notif_layout" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: No. This does not cut it. I have derived my theme from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar which does not include ActionBar. And titlebar should be hidden in any case.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you set toolbar resolved your problem"?

Comment: with toolbar you can easily customize your actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create such a style.xml.Its for full screen app.So just delete fullscreen for NoTitleBar.And windowFullScreen to false.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And such a Mansifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="by.test.roma.usermetrics" >

    <application
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried all of that allready. Besides there is already defined theme Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar. It just doesn't work.